# Dovecot: migrate to virtual mailboxes

Tags: linux, dovecot, migration

I have a linux server currently running Dovecot 2.3. Each user has a system account. The email are stored in format Maildir (mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir).

The new setup should use virtual mailboxes with a different layout (mail_location = maildir:~/mail:LAYOUT=fs)

How can I migrate the emails to the new location (/home//Maildir => /var/vmail/mailboxes///mail) with the new layout? I tried doveadm sync but so far without luck.